# Git "push" to somewhere other than "origin" 

Tags: git, github

I am using Git to publish some code to GitHub. This is my first time using Git so I only know what I need to at the moment. I am using multiple computers at home to do changes. Can I push my changes from one computer to another before pushing to GitHub?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set up another remote, if the other computer has a Git or HTTP server running on it:

```
git remote add your-other-computer git://your.other.computer/...
git push your-other-computer master
```

I find it's easier to host a read-only repository over HTTP on each computer (by sharing my Git directory over Apache or IIS), then log onto the other computer and `git pull`.

Comment: whats wrong with using ssh? would be way easier then hosting via http

Comment: Depends where I am - Windows comes with IIS built in, and on my home network I don't need the security of SSH

Comment: but HTTP is generally slower that git/ssh protocol.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to do this all the time :). But I find that HTTP is a decent lowest common denominator on Windows.

Comment: what is 'git://your.other.computer/...'? What shall I write in case if I want to add my local machine as one of the remote?

Comment: @ObaidMaroof To push to another directory on the same computer, put the directory path here instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can push and pull from your other git repositories just like you would to Github…

```
git push [remote] [branch]
```

However, **you cannot push to a checked-out branch in a non-bare repository.**

In other words, if I want to push my changes in the master branch to my laptop from my desktop and my laptop already has the master branch checked out, Git will refuse to do it. This is to keep you from losing work, and because it's obtrusive to do.

Of course, if you run a bare repository (no working tree) you can push to it without any issues related to this, but then again you can't really work from within that repository without doing a clone and pushing back into it.

Dropbox, as suggested by Harpyon, isn't actually too bad an idea if you're syncing your own computers. I know some really smart developers that have been doing it for a while, sans problem.

Comment: So I would have to create a "bare" repo on dropbox (I have iDisk too btw) and push the changes to there, then pull them from my other "workstation" ?

Comment: No, you wouldn't push or pull to a dropboxed repository except to sync it with a repository that isn't in the dropbox. You would be pushing and pulling from the same repository otherwise. Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

If neither is a bare repository, it's better to pull (or fetch) than push, because you have more control over the merging. For this reason git will not permit pushing to a checked-out branch in a non-bare repository, as coreyward points out.

The best process would probably be to set up [git daemon](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) on the machine you want to pull from, and then configure a remote:

```
git remote add my-other-repo git://path/to/other/repo
```

Then you can pull from that repository:

```
git checkout branch-you-want-to-be-on
git pull my-other-repo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can synchronize the repository using Dropbox. That's what I'm currently doing, and it works just fine. If not, you have to use one of the computers as a server of some sort, using e.g. SSH.

Comment: Using dropbox to share is counter to using git to begin with and seems to be a good way to loose a change.

Comment: I see what you mean, but using Dropbox to sync it before pushing to a server is much easier than setting up your own server, and I haven't had any problems with it yet.

Comment: @Dan: Yeah, I know several devs that do this without any issue to sync their own machines. It's much easier than constantly adding remotes to repositories.